# mysql_real_escape_string deleting entire string

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I'm writing an authentication system for my site and I want to ensure I'm protected against SQL injection. I'm using 'mysql_real_escape_string' but this clears out the string completely. the username is something like 'Damo' but after running through the function it's gone.

What am I doing wrong? (it works fine without mysql_real_escape_string)

```
$user_name = $_POST["username"];
$md5 = md5($_POST["password"]);

$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($user_name);


$login = $query->GetSingleQuery("--SINGLE","SELECT user_name, id FROM url_users WHERE user_name='".$user_name."' and user_password='".$md5."';",array("user_name","id"));
```

Comment: Do you have magic quotes turned on? (get_magic_quotes_gpc())

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) requires a connection. The connection is assumed to have been created as part of the same library.

However, `mysql_real_escape_string` is not OO-based, and you're clearly using some other library for your OO `$query` (*what is it?*). So `mysql_real_escape_string` cannot "see" the connection that you're using, and thus it cannot work.

If you turn error reporting on (and you really should), you ought to see an `E_WARNING` generated for this.

For now, I suggest `mysql_escape_string` instead. Its use may not match the character set of your database connection, but it'll do you for now, and it doesn't require a connection. Ideally, use the escaping function provided through the DB library that you're *actually* using.

Comment: I'm an idiot. mysql_real_escape_string is already included in the SQL connection class I'm using. 

Thanks for your input, it made me look in the right place.

Comment: @Damo: No problem. Absolutely use the function provided in the library you're using; it will be aware of the connection you've created, and thus it will function properly. And turn on error reporting! Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

try this snippet, i think your wrong on what's actully happening.

```
$user_name = $_POST["username"];
echo 'before: '.$user_name;
$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($user_name);
echo 'after: '.$user_name;
```